# Pick larger number from two lists

Tags: list, erlang

I want to pick numbers from two lists of the same size into another list. Larger numbers gets picked.

For example:

```
[1,2,3,4] and [5,5,0,1] ----> [5,5,3,4]
```

Is there an elegant way in Erlang to do this? Using List comprehensions maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 lists:map(fun({F,S}) -> max(F, S) end, lists:zip(L1, L2)).
```

Answer (score 4):

With list comprehensions:

```
A = [1,2,3,4],
B = [5,5,0,1],
[max(X, Y) || {X,Y} <- lists:zip(A,B)].
```

Returns:

```
> [5,5,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to traverse the list twice:

```
A = [1,2,3,4],
B = [5,5,0,1],
lists:zipwith(fun erlang:max/2, A, B).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1> L1 = [1,2,3,4], L2 = [5,5,0,1].
2> lists:zipwith(fun (X, Y) when X > Y -> X;
                     (X, Y) when X =< Y -> Y end, L1, L2).
[5,5,3,4]
```